# When using ant to run jmeter, is it possible to fail test cases not only based in HTTP status codes but also in response time?

Tags: performance, ant, jmeter

I just did a quick test to run jmeter using Ant. I see an html report that shows success rate based on HTTP status codes:

[Ant Jmeter Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icRuk.png)

Is it possible to do anything so that say, requests that take more than 1 second are considered as failures too?

So in short I want the report to show failure when the HTTP code is not 2XX and also when response time greater than say 1 sec

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. In order to check HTTP Status code being 2xx add a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to the Sampler(s) which you want to have checked (JMeter Assertions respect [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules)) and configure it like:

   [image]
2. In order to conditionally fail requests which take longer than 1 second add [Duration Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) (the same Scoping Rules apply) and configure it like:

   [image]

Check out [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps) article to learn more how you can conditionally mark JMeter samplers as passed/failed using Assertions.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your test [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion)
 with value of 1000 
(Milliseconds)

> Duration in Milliseconds
>   The maximum number of milliseconds each response is allowed before being marked as failed.